# Plural form of abbreviations and using a period at the end

Tags: british-english, abbreviations, periods

I was reading in [Mignon Fogerty's Quickanddirtytips_When you need periods after abbreviations](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/when-you-need-periods-after-abbreviations) about the guidelines she gives covering the use of periods at the end of abbreviations ... when you should do so; but now I am wondering whether these guidelines change when abbreviating the *plural* form of the word?

**For example:**

```
Word: Extension
US Abbreviation: Ext.
British Abbreviation: Ext.
```

**Plural:**

```
Word: Extensions
US Abbreviation: Exts.
British Abbreviation: Exts. or Exts
```

Now using the guidelines from that page, **US English** always uses a period at the end of abbreviations so it would be `Exts.`; however **British English** denotes that you only use a period at the end when the *last* letter of abbreviation *doesn't* match the last letter of the full word.

With that in mind then that is why with the *non-plurlal* version you end up using `Ext.`, but the question now is, do we keep following this tandard and just append an `s` to the end for `Exts.` or do we know say the `s` at the end of the abbreviation now matches the `s` at the end of the full word and instead use `Exts`?

Comment: I think the implication that BrE only *discards* the period when the last letters *do* match is misleading. For all practical purposes, I think the position is that BrE orthography is less "conservative" than AmE in this area. And since the general trend is increasingly to discard the period after familiar and much-used abbreviations, Brits naturally tend to use any excuse. Hence later usages, particularly BrE, tend to favour ***revs per minute*** with no period (***rev*** and ***revolution*** don't end with the same letter, but ***revs*** and ***revolutions*** do, and that's good enough! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Some interesting points - thanks! :)

Comment: The idea that all Anglophones in the UK speak one form of English and all Anglophones in the US speak a second form is best discarded ASAP. I've found a style guide licensing eg, ie etc and find that this style best avoids problems with dual punctuation etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Could you explain your second sentence a little more - I didn't quite understand it?

Comment: (2) I don't end up writing << ... this style best avoids problems with dual punctuation etc.. >> (1) Look at [Abbreviations and full stops](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58236/abbreviations-and-full-stops/209060#209060), especially choster's and Barrie England's answers and tunny's reference to Swan ('We usually write abbreviations without full stops in modern British English' [Michael Swan, Practical English Usage,2005.2]). I've forgotten which style guide recommends periodless ex-Latin abbreviations, but Swan is a recognised authority and includes all abbreviations....

Comment: Though doubtless he advocates using a full stop where needed for disambiguation. Note however that Kris has a different **_opinion_** (and it can be seen that these matters ultimately boil down to matters of opinion, if only about where clarification / standardisation is essential). You yourself choose to quote from one particular style guide here.

Comment: Presumably not all Americans always take it for granted all abbreviations will be followed by a period, or [the Webster's Dictionary "dord" howler](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/dord) would never have come about.